# Выделение поддомена при регистрации

Tags: php

Нужно выделять для каждого зарегистрированного пользователя поддомен, при регистрации.

Адрес анкеты пользователя: **site.com/usernickname**, его анкета должна быть доступной и по адресу **usernickname.site.com**.

Как такое организовать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

В ДНС добавить субдомен с именем `*` и после этого брать информацию об имени пользователя не из `REQUEST_URI`, а из `HTTP_HOST`